# Web Page Login doesn't work before execute Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, jdbc

Good morning.
I am curious about the problem I have.

I made a web page with JSP, Tomcat, Oracle(v11).
And web page works normaly while I am connecting to Oracle DB with Sql Developer.

---The problem is,
if I shut sql developer down(Not Oracle Server, just sql developer),
after while, I couldn't login the web page.
And Oracle Server still running.

So I run sql developer and connected to oracle server,
then login system works again.
the account information used by JDBC and sql developer are the same.

It would be very appreciated that if you give me an advice.
Thank you.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Why is this tagged `sql-server`?  That is Microsoft's relational database.  Is that involved somehow?  What error do you get?  It is highly, highly unlikely that the error your JSP application gets has aything to do with whether a different client application is running.

Comment: How do you run your web app, from Eclipse or some other IDE? If so, what's the output in the console?